# Error while reading File with Bash

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, scripting

I want to read a File in a bash script with the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

file=$(sort "$1" | cut -f 1 -d "," | uniq -c | sed 's/^ *//g')

while IFS= read -r line
do
    echo "$line"
done < "$file"
```

But at the end of the file I always get this error:

```
File name too long
```

Why does this occur?
And at the beginning I get this output, but don't want it:

```
script.sh: line 8:
```

Comment: what's the file name you are passing to this script?

Comment: input.csv is the file name

Comment: your script does save all the file content into variable `file=` but your loop is trying to read from a file named <content> (and this file does of course not exist) https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/593292

Comment: I got this point and tried to solve it in the post you cited. But that's not the best solution, because I want to solve it without buffering a file on the device.

Answer (score 3):

The variable `file` doesn't seem to contain a filename after processing. If you want to process the output of your command, you could use a process substitution `<(...)`:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r line; do
  printf '%s\n' "$line"
done < <(sort "$1" | cut -f1 -d, | uniq -c | sed 's/^ *//')
```

Note that I removed the `g` in your `sed` script since the beginning of the line `^` followed by any amount of spaces matches only once per line.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [Here String](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Strings) for the redirection into the whileloop

```bsh
data=$(sort "$1" | cut -f 1 -d "," | uniq -c | sed 's/^ *//')
while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "$line"
done <<< "$data"
```

Or capture the pipeline output into an array with [readarray](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-readarray)

```bsh
readarray -t data < <(sort "$1" | cut -f 1 -d "," | uniq -c | sed 's/^ *//')
for line in "${data[@]}"; do
    echo "$line"
done
# to print without a loop:
printf "%s\n" "${data[@]}"
```